# why is resultset.next() returning null

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

in the code below the method resultset.next() is returning false

```
String sql = "{?= call fun_consolidate_retrieve_vector_receipt_payment_details(?,?,?,?,?,?)}";
        callableStatement = con.prepareCall(sql);
        callableStatement = con.prepareCall(" {? = call fun_retrieve_vector_receipt_payment_details(?,?,?,?,?,?)}");
        callableStatement.registerOutParameter(1, Types.OTHER);
        callableStatement.setString(2, "PAYMENT");
        callableStatement.setInt(3, 47);
        callableStatement.setString(4, "24-05-2013");
        callableStatement.setString(5, "24-09-2013");
        callableStatement.setString(6, "Y");
        callableStatement.setObject(7, resultSet);
        con.setAutoCommit(false);
        callableStatement.execute();

        resultSet = (ResultSet) callableStatement.getObject(1);
        boolean next = resultSet.next();
```

Why is it so??? if i call same stored procedure from my database it results in 2 rows of output(provding same input as in java code)

Comment: You might want to take a second look at those `setString` calls where you're passing date-strings: are you sure the dates are being parsed the way you expect?

Comment: I think this link will help http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/refman-5.5-en/connector-j-usagenotes-statements-callable.html

Comment: Please show us the source of the function `fun_consolidate_retrieve_vector_receipt_payment_details`

Answer (score 1):

Your title expresses your confusion. ResultSet.next() returns a *boolean,* not anything that can be null. You need to call it *before* getObject(), not afterwards.

Comment: Because the unknown stored procedure you called didn't select any rows. You should also consider defining the SQL that calls it once, not twice.